# Walk from Attribute to CustomAttributeData or backwards

Tags: c#, reflection, custom-attributes, system.reflection

**Question.** Is there a way to get an instance of `CustomAttributeData` based on the given instance of my custom attribute, say, `MyAttribute`? Or vice versa?

**Why do I need this?** The instance of `MyAttribute` contains properties I am interested in, while the instance of `CustomAttributeData` contains actual constructor parameters I am interested in. So now I implement double work: *first*, get the instance of `MyAttribute` by calling

```
Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(property, typeof(MyAttribute)) as MyAttribute
```

, and *second*, get the instance of `CustomAttributeData` by calling

```
CustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributes(property)
```

and walking over this collection.

**P. S.** I have taken a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895802/reflection-emit-how-to-convert-attribute-instance-to-customattributebuilder-or), but didn't find the desired solution there.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you already have an instance of the custom attribute MyAttributeInstance, and you want to get the CustomAttributeData for that same instance, preferably in one step.

Since you already found the MyAttributeInstance, and that is attached to a property (or a class, or...), I will assume you have the property available. So this could *possibly* work for you:

```
CustomAttributeData CAD = property.GetCustomAttributesData().First(x => x.AttributeType == MyAttributeInstance.GetType());
```

I think that answers your actual question. However, I think your intent *might* have been to actually ask how to get the CustomAttributeData from a property directly. In that case try this:

```
CustomAttributeData CAD = property.GetCustomAttributesData().First(x => x.AttributeType == typeof(MyAttribute));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems to me (I cannot remember it exactly however) that what I asked about was how to, having an instance of Attribute class, get an instance of CustomAttributeData class. In this case your answer only suggests another way of obtaining an instance of CustomAttributeData class while having an instance of PropertyInfo class (the other way was proposed in the question).

Comment: If you have two attributes of same type applied to one property this code will give values of first one